# Page margins problem with the title page and rest of the pages in the chapter

Tags: margins, chapters, geometry

I am writing a thesis, and the university has some rules. The word `Chapter` should be 2in from the top of the page, and the for the rest of the pages, the text should start 1.25in from the top edge. I am using the directions from here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout

The pagestyle is `plain`. So I use these parameters:

```
   \documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newcommand{\setdimensions}{
    %
    % Horizontal
    %
    \setlength{\hoffset}       {0.00 in} % 1.00 in
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin} {0.26 in} % 1.25 in
    \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.26 in} % 1.25 in
    \setlength{\textwidth}     {6.6 in} % 7.75 in
    \setlength{\marginparsep}  {0.00 in} % 7.75 in
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{-0.1 in} % 7.75 in
    %                                    % 8.50 in
    %
    %
    % Vertical
    %
    \setlength{\voffset}   {-0.43 in}              %  0.75 in
    \setlength{\topmargin} { 0.00 in}              %  0.75 in
    \setlength{\headheight}{ 0.200636502006365 in} %  0.200636502006365 in
    \setlength{\headsep}   { 0.475 in} %  0.299363497993635 in
    \setlength{\textheight}{ 8.60 in}               %  9.75 in
    \setlength{\footskip}  { 0.55 in}              % 10.25 in
                                                   % 11.00 in
}

\setdimensions

\newcommand\utdchapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@utdchapter\@schapter}

\def\@utdchapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\chaptername\, \protect\numberline{\thechapter} \uppercase{#1}}%
                    \else
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\chaptername\, \uppercase{#1}}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}



\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

This gives a gap of 1.5in for all the non-title pages in the thesis. I want to change it to 1.25in without altering anything in the title page.

Comment: Do you use a template of your university or do you the layout by your own? If you are using a template please name it or give us a link. If not which class do you use? a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i solved my problem by introducing this:

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0.00in}{0.4in}{5mm}
```

Answer (score 3):

Page geometry settings are best set using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). The following solution is based on the assumption that you are using one of the standard document classes that provides `\chapter` functionality (like [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls), say).

It would be best to keep the margins fixed, and alter the chapter title macro. The two involved with the chapter setting are `\@makechapterhead` (associated with `\chapter`) and `\@makeschapterhead` (associated with `\chapter*`). The usual gap between the top of the text block and the word `Chapter` is `50\p@` (or `50pt`). I've adapted that, together with a supply of the `geometry` package parameters (vertically; not exactly sure about your horizontal requirements).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[showframe,
  top=1.25in,
  bottom=1.25in,
  includeheadfoot,
  left=0.26in,
  textwidth=6.6in,
  headsep=0.3in,
  headheight=0.2in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{\dimexpr2in-1.25in-0.3in-0.2in-\topskip}% Used to be 50\p@
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{\dimexpr2in-1.25in-0.3in-0.2in-\topskip}% Used to be 50\p@
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Note that the absolute top of the word `Chapter` is *not* at `2in` from the page boundary. However, the top of line (in `\huge` font, with a `\baselineskip` of `25pt`) is exactly `2in` from the page boundary. This can be changed, if needed.

The `showframe` option shows the text block, margin width and header/footer.

Comment: I have edited the question, and given a MWE, if you run it, you will see that the second page has a gap of 1.5in from the top. I want to change it to 1.25in without altering anything in the title page.